# Correct type for binary file-like object

Tags: python-3.x, file, binary, pycharm, type-hinting

I have the following functions defined using Python type-hinting:

```
from typing import BinaryIO

def do_something(filename: str):
    my_file = open(filename, "rb")
    read_data(my_file)

def read_data(some_binary_readable_thing: BinaryIO):
    pass
```

However my IDE (PyCharm 2017.2) gives me the following warning on the line I invoke `read_file`:

```
Expected type 'BinaryIO', got 'FileIO[bytes]' instead
```

What is the correct type for me to use here? [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module) defines the `BinaryIO` as "a simple subtype of `IO[bytes]`". Does `FileIO` not conform to `IO`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a bug in either Pycharm or `typing` module. From the `typing.py` module:

```
class BinaryIO(IO[bytes]):
    """Typed version of the return of open() in binary mode."""
    ...
```

Also the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.io) specifies:

> These represent the types of I/O streams such as returned by open().

So it **should** work as stated. For now, a workaround would be to explicitly use `FileIO`.

```
from io import FileIO

def do_something(filename: str):
    my_file = open(filename, "rb")
    read_data(my_file)

def read_data(some_binary_readable_thing: FileIO[bytes]):
    pass
```